# Wait 20 Seconds In Timer Before Executing Next Line Without Thread.Sleep.C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to wait for 20 seconds before adding + 1 value to i (Int), But i want to do it without `Thread.Sleep`.

This is my code, By the way I'm not a Pro programmer.

```
private void Refresh_App_TimerNH_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label18.Text = "Timer Activated";
    int i = 0;
    i = i + 1;
    if (i == 16)
    {
        i = 0;
    }
    else
    {

    }
    if (i == 1)
    {
        webBrowser1.Refresh();
        userIdLabel1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        label20.Text = "+1";
     //**i want to add 20 second gap here**
        i = i + 1;
    }
    else
    {

    }
    if (i == 2)
    {
        webBrowser2.Refresh();
        userIdLabel2.BackColor = Color.Red;
        label20.Text = "+2";
        i = i + 1;
    }
    else
    {

    }
    if (i == 3)
    {
        webBrowser3.Refresh();
        userIdLabel3.BackColor = Color.Red;
        label20.Text = "+3";
        i = i + 1;
    }
    else
    {

    }
    if (i == 4)
    {
        webBrowser4.Refresh();
        userIdLabel4.BackColor = Color.Red;
        label20.Text = "+4";
        i = i + 1;
    }
    else
    {

    }
    if (i == 5)
    {
        webBrowser5.Refresh();
        userIdLabel5.BackColor = Color.Red;
        label20.Text = "+5";
        i = i + 1;
    }
    else
    {

    }
    if (i == 6)
    {
        webBrowser6.Refresh();
        userIdLabel6.BackColor = Color.Red;
        label20.Text = "+6";
        i = i + 1;
    }
    else
    {

    }
    if (i == 7)
    {
        webBrowser7.Refresh();
        userIdLabel7.BackColor = Color.Red;
        label20.Text = "+7";
        i = i + 1;
    }
    else
    {

    }
    if (i == 8)
    {
        webBrowser8.Refresh();
        userIdLabel8.BackColor = Color.Red;
        label20.Text = "+8";
        i = i + 1;
    }
    else
    {

    }
    if (i == 9)
    {
        webBrowser9.Refresh();
        userIdLabel9.BackColor = Color.Red;
        label20.Text = "+9";
        i = i + 1;
    }
    else
    {

    }
    if (i == 10)
    {
        webBrowser10.Refresh();
        userIdLabel10.BackColor = Color.Red;
        label20.Text = "+10";
        i = i + 1;
    }
    else
    {

    }
    if (i == 11)
    {
        webBrowser11.Refresh();
        userIdLabel11.BackColor = Color.Red;
        label20.Text = "+11";
        i = i + 1;
    }
    else
    {

    }
    if (i == 12)
    {
        webBrowser12.Refresh();
        userIdLabel12.BackColor = Color.Red;
        label20.Text = "+12";
        i = i + 1;
    }
    else
    {

    }
    if (i == 13)
    {
        webBrowser13.Refresh();
        userIdLabel13.BackColor = Color.Red;
        label20.Text = "+13";
        i = i + 1;
    }
    else
    {

    }
    if (i == 14)
    {
        webBrowser14.Refresh();
        userIdLabel14.BackColor = Color.Red;
        label20.Text = "+14";
        i = i + 1;
    }
    else
    {

    }
    if (i == 15)
    {
        webBrowser15.Refresh();
        userIdLabel15.BackColor = Color.Red;
        label20.Text = "+15";
        i = i + 1;
    }
    else
    {

    }
    if (i == 16)
    {
        webBrowser16.Refresh();
        userIdLabel16.BackColor = Color.Red;
        label20.Text = "+16";
        i = i + 1;
    }
    else
    {

    }
    Refresh_App_TimerNH.Stop();
    label18.Text = "Timer De-Activated";
    Refresh_App_TimerNH.Start();

}
```

I think it might be easy but not for me, Because i'm new to c#

Comment: And what problem are you having with that code?

Comment: you aren't required to put an `else` statement after an `if`.  You can remove all those.  Of course you can make all this code incredibly shorter

Comment: Let me edit it on the question

Comment: Please shorten your code and tell us there you need to wait

Comment: Respected Members,
i have edited it and added where i want the 20 second gap

Comment: every time your timer ticks you're just running through all your `if` statements.  I assume you decided you don't want `Thread.Sleep` because it's freezing your application.

Comment: Yes @Jonesy,
How can make it wait without `Thread.Sleep`?

Comment: Is this WPF? WinForms? WebForms? Something else? That will decide what timer you can and should use.

Comment: This Is WinForm @TimS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, Tim S's answer -- break up your logic into smaller chunks and simplify the timer logic -- is good. But to answer your specific question, which was "how do I delay between statements without `Sleep`", is:  make the method `async` and then use `await Task.Delay(...)`.

You are right to avoid `Sleep`; using it is a bad programming practice, and will hang your application. `await Task.Delay` does an *asynchronous wait* -- that is, the method returns immediately, the app keeps on processing UI messages, and when the delay is done, the program schedules the remainder of the method to execute later.

Note that during an asynchronous wait, by design messages keep on getting processed. If one of those messages causes your event handler to run *again* then you can get into the very confusing situation of having multiple control points *in the same non-recursive method*.  Try to avoid that.

Comment: For the purposes of what he's doing here, I figured using the timer as the delay was appropriate. For general use, `async` as you describe is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Right now your logic is convoluted, and probably very different from what you want it to do.

Your code will be much simpler if you put your `webBrowserX` and `userIdLabelX` items in some sort of list together.

```
public class MyPair
{
    public WebBrowser WebBrowser { get; set; }
    public Label UserIdLabel { get; set; }
}
private List<MyPair> pairs;
private int refreshIndex = 0;
private void StartTimer()
{
    pairs = // populate pairs somehow
    refreshIndex = 0;
    var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 20000
    timer.Tick += MyTickHandler;
    timer.Start();
    label18.Text = "Timer Activated";
}
private void MyTickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pairs[refreshIndex].WebBrowser.Refresh();
    pairs[refreshIndex].UserIdLabel.BackColor = Color.Red;
    label20.Text = "+" + (refreshIndex + 1);
    refreshIndex = (refreshIndex + 1) % pairs.Count;
}
```

Note that this timer never deactivates, it loops through the list of pairs repeatedly.